# Attach Keyboard Hook to Specific Window

Tags: python, windows, winapi

Am new to Windows API & DLLs. Am using Python 3.6.4 32-bit and pkgs cffi, pywin32.

I want to attach a keyboard hook to a specific running application (example being Notepad) and print out pressed keycodes until I stop monitoring the program.

I noticed Microsoft docs said that for the `SetWindowsHookExA` function, `dwThreadId` can be used to associate the hook with a specific thread (but the hook procedure must be contained in a DLL).

So, I've converted my hook procedure from python to a DLL via the `cffi` module.

**hookProc.py**

```
ffibuilder.embedding_api("""
    LRESULT keyboard_callback(int, WPARAM, LPARAM);
""")

ffibuilder.set_source("DLLs.hook_proc",
"""
    #include <Windows.h>
""")

ffibuilder.embedding_init_code("""
    from hook_proc import ffi
    from ctypes import *
    import sys

    @ffi.def_extern()
    def keyboard_callback(nCode, wParam, lParam):
        print(nCode, wParam, lParam[0])
        if (lParam[0] == 162):
            sys.exit(0)
        # First arg is ignored according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-callnexthookex
        return windll.user32.CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam)
""")

ffibuilder.compile(target="hookedProc.*", verbose=True)
```

Running it produces `hookProc.dll`. I get a DLL handle via `LoadLibraryW` and the the address of the exported func `keyboard_callback` via `GetProcAddress`. I pass those to `SetWindowsHookExA` alongside the thread id of the running program (Notepad) via `GetWindowThreadProcessId`.

**keyboard.py**

```
import win32gui;
import atexit;
import ctypes
from ctypes import *;
from ctypes import wintypes;
from typing import Union;
from ctypes.wintypes import DWORD

WH_KEYBOARD = c_int(2)
LEFT_CTRL = 162
WINDOW_TITLE = "Untitled - Notepad"

windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExA.argtypes = (c_int, wintypes.HANDLE, wintypes.HMODULE, wintypes.DWORD)

class Window:
    def __init__(self, hwnd, x, y, width, height):
        self.hwnd = hwnd
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    def get_thread_id(self):
        threadId = windll.user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(self.hwnd, None)
        return threadId

class WindowMngr:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def get_window(title: str) -> Union[Window, None]:
        hwnd: str = win32gui.FindWindow(None, title)
        if not hwnd is None:
            left, top, right, bottom = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
            return Window(hwnd, left, top, right - left, bottom - top)
        return None

# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-kbdllhookstruct?redirectedfrom=MSDN
class KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT(ctypes.Structure):
    __fields__ = [
                    ("vkCode", DWORD),
                    ("scanCode", DWORD),
                    ("flags", DWORD),
                    ("time", DWORD),
                    ("dwExtraInfo", POINTER(wintypes.ULONG)),
                ]

class KeyboardMngr:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.hookId = None

    def register_hook(self) -> bool:

        tid = DWORD(WindowMngr.get_window(WINDOW_TITLE).get_thread_id())
        print(f"Window '{WINDOW_TITLE}' thread id = {tid}")

        dllHandle = windll.kernel32.LoadLibraryW("DLLs/hookedProc")
        print("DLL Handle @ ", dllHandle)
        hkProcPtr = windll.kernel32.GetProcAddress(dllHandle, 2)
        print("Hook proc  @ ", hkProcPtr)

        self.hookId = windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExA(
            WH_KEYBOARD,
            hkProcPtr,
            dllHandle,
            tid
        )

        if not self.hookId:
            return False

        # Register to remove the hook when the interpreter exits.
        atexit.register(windll.user32.UnhookWindowsHookEx, self.hookId)
        print("Hook Id is ", self.hookId)

        while True:
            msg = windll.user32.GetMessageW(None, 0, 0,0)
            windll.user32.TranslateMessage(byref(msg))
            windll.user32.DispatchMessageW(byref(msg))

keyboardMngr = KeyboardMngr()

def main():
    keyboardMngr.register_hook()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Problems:

- `GetProcAddress` doesn't return an address when I specify the exported func name "keyboard_callback". I have checked that the exported name is indeed "keyboard_callback" by doing `dumpbin /exports hookedProc.dll`. I don't know why it doesn't work, so I've used the ordinal number instead (blindly hoping that it does refer to the keyboard hook proc).
  [image: dllDump]
- Running keyboard.py results in execution stopping immediately -- despite the message loop it should be hitting. I'm pretty sure `hookId` shouldn't be zero, so something must be wrong with my `SetWindowsHookExA` call, but I'm not sure what.
  [image: ExecutionResult]

Insight/help much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa#return-value) fails. Check error code via calling `GetLastError()`.

Comment: You cannot possibly filter input by target process in a low-level keyboard hook. The system doesn't know, where the input ultimately goes while handling low-level hooks. You don't need a DLL (as documented) and you cannot pass a thread ID either (as documented). Fixing bugs isn't going to produce a solution. You're going to have to scrap the entire approach. You don't have any other options.

Comment: If window have specific name or substring in name you can check it first in your script with `GetForegroundWindow` and `GetWindowText`

Comment: @vii How is that supposed to help? I mean, why not simply install a keyboard hook on the desired thread(s) and be done with it. No heavy-handed approach like you are suggesting required. Though, of course, that, too, assumes that you read and comprehend the published documentation.

Comment: @IInspectable it's just walk-around and not heavy at all. Something like `if not 'Notepad' in GetWindowText( GetForegroundWindow() ): return`

Comment: @vii It's the most brittle approach imaginable. Input may or may not go to the foreground window. And *any* window can return `Notepad` in response to a call to `GetWindowText`. Incidentally, Notepad won't.

Comment: @IInspectable "any window can return Notepad" this is ridiculous. I use thist approach a hundred times a day and it works without issues.

Comment: Newsflash: *"Works on my machine"* is not a generally accepted metric of quality.

Comment: @IInspectable "you cannot pass a thread ID either (as documented)" where is this documented? I thought that was the purpose of the fourth argument as it states "The identifier of the thread with which the hook procedure is to be associated." [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa#parameters).

Comment: That's for *local* hooks. Low-level hooks are always global. As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw).